# Why is my pipeline suddenly timing out when running webpack?

Tags: azure, webpack, timeout, azure-pipelines

I have this step in my azure pipeline yaml:

```
- task: webpack@4
  displayName: webpack
  inputs:
    webpackCliArguments: '--config webpack.$(buildConfiguration).config.js'
    workingFolder: $(projects.workingFolders.webApi)
```

It has always worked fine, and generally this step in the pipeline is done in around 8 minutes or so

Recently, I added these `[contenthash]` changes to `webpack.config.js` to prevent users having to hard refresh after a change has been deployed:

```
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';    plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: devMode ? "[name].bundle.css" : "[name].[contenthash].bundle.css"
    })
],

output: {
    .... ....
    filename: devMode ? "[name].bundle.js" : "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js" 
},
```

Now suddently the pipeline will hang on `webpack` step, and after an hours times out, cancelling the entire run. **This happens intermittently, and seems to happen on every 2nd run on average**

> ##[error]The operation was canceled.

I have no proof that my change is what caused this, but the timing is pretty coincidental.

Does anyone know whether or not a hang like this can be caused by using `[contenthash]` in the filename for webpack outputs? Alternatively, **does anyone know how I can possibly debug this problem**?

For instance, how can I get webpack to log any issues to the azure pipeline window? console.log does not seem to work.

---

After setting `system.debug=true` I can now see the below message in the logs

```
executing the command: node --inspect "E:\Builds\RemoteAgent1\_work\613\s\Project\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js" --json --config webpack.Release.config.js --display verbose
##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'webpack'.
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the build machine in VSTS. How to debug that depends on how your have these configured

Comment: @Liam thanks for the comment Liam - any clue on how I can investigate that? Not sure what build machine in vsts means

Comment: Who manages your VSTS (Azure-devops or whatever MS are calling it this week) subscription? when this is configured you'll setup build agents. These actually run the pipelines. I'm guessing the issue is there

Comment: @Liam I should be able to access those, but not sure what I can check or how to add some logging. Do you have any more clues?

Answer (score 0):

Still not really sure what the issue was here, we but managed to resolve it by remove `thread-lodaer` from webpack config `module.rules`:

```
...
    {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'thread-loader',                                         // remove this line
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }
        ]
    },
...
```

It doesn't seem to have caused any issues so far